# Golang debug with gbd can't open to read symbols?

Tags: macos, debugging, go, gdb

I debug my code referencing [Debugging Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)

But when I run `gdb xxx.test`, I get a list Warning:

```
Reading symbols from markdown.test...
warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_amd64.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_darwin_amd64.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_setenv.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_util.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/rn/ff65_68n0kg4_ml_v420yg5m0000gn/T/go-build619623895/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre/_obj/pcre.cgo2.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Using `go test -c -work` instead of `go test -c`

```
warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_amd64.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_darwin_amd64.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_setenv.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

warning: `/var/folders/00/0sdwh000h01000cxqpysvccm0035qk/T/go-build765783040/runtime/cgo/_obj/gcc_util.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
```

`source /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py` within gdb

```
Loading Go Runtime support.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py", line 205, in <module>
    _rctp_type = gdb.lookup_type("struct runtime.rtype").pointer()
gdb.error: No struct type named runtime.rtype.
```

After editing **runtime-gdb.py**

```
line 205: `#_rctp_type = gdb.lookup_type("struct runtime._type").pointer()`
line 216: `return go_type_ptr.cast(gdb.lookup_type("struct reflect.rtype").pointer()).dereference()`
```

source runtime-gdb.py within gdb

```
(gdb) source /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
Loading Go Runtime support.
```

And then I cannot do next step.Is anyone know how to fix it?

- go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64
- GDB:7.9 (using homebrew to install)
- OS:Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: `go test -c` builds `dirname.test` but discards the temporary source that it marked up and used to build the test executable. Perhaps something like `go test -c -work` may do what you want, but then it'd be up to you to remove that temporary work directory when finished.

Comment: @DaveC , When I run `go test -c -work` ,command line output `WORK=/var/folders/rn/ff65_68n0kg4_ml_v420yg5m0000gn/T/go-build702663380
`. And there is not **00**  in **/var/folders** . It still fails

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't actually read the link you gave, and assumed it was something to do with you debugging a test (my bad!). But they use a test executable as their example and do so *without* using `-work`. Did you do `gdb xxx.test -d $GOROOT` (with GOROOT set, or substitute `$(go env GOROOT)`)? Did you try sourcing `runtime-gdb.py` from within gdb if the previous failed? I don't use OS X so I can't help more than those useless suggestions; sorry. :(

Comment: @DaveC , thanks! it work fine referencing official doc in Ubuntu. But still don't work in OS X.